# Python Telegram. Не работает функция для вводы Random

Tags: python, telegram

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import random
import config

request_headers = {
        "Accept-Language": "ru"
    }

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def language(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.row('English', 'Random')
    # markup.row("Other", "Random")
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Choose language:", reply_markup=markup)
    if send.text == "Random":
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send, languages_other)

def languages_other(message):
    if message.text == "Random":
        l_i_s_t = ["አማርኛ", "عرب", "Afrikaans"]
        random.shuffle(l_i_s_t)
        list_random = ""
        for i in l_i_s_t:
            list_random = i
        list_random = list_random[0]
        message.text = list_random
    elif message.text == "አማርኛ":
        am = {"Accept-Language": "am"}
        request_headers.update(am)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'የአየር ሁኔታን ለማወቅ የሚፈልጉትን ቦታ ይምረጡ')
    elif message.text == "عرب":
        ar = {"Accept-Language": "ar"}
        request_headers.update(ar)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'اختر مكانًا تريد معرفة الطقس فيه')
    elif message.text == "Afrikaans":
        af = {"Accept-Language": "af"}
        request_headers.update(af)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Kies 'n plek waar jy die weer wil weet")
bot.infinity_polling()
```